# HTML5 WebSocket with hybi-17

Tags: html, websocket, handshake, phpwebsocket

**Update**: I solved the decoding problem, thanks to *pimvdb*

Follows the solution (in PHP):

```
$len = $masks = $data = $decoded = null;

$len = ord ($buffer[1]) & 127;

if ($len === 126) {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 4, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 8);
}
else if ($len === 127) {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 10, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 14);
}
else {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 2, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 6);
}

for ($index = 0; $index < strlen ($data); $index++) {
  $decoded .= $data[$index] ^ $masks[$index % 4];
}
```

*** Begin of the original topic ***

I'm trying to develop HTML5 WebSocket for a personal application, using **[hybi-17 handshake](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17)**.

I'm started with **[phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)** and the only thing I changed is the handshake function, from the original to this:

```
function dohandshake($user,$buffer){
  $key = null;
  
  console("\nRequesting handshake...");
  console($buffer);
  console("Handshaking...");
  
  preg_match ("#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*?)\r\n#", $buffer, $match) && $key = $match[1];
  
  $key .= "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
  $key = sha1 ($key);
  $key = pack ('H*', $key);
  $key = base64_encode ($key);
  
  $upgrade = 
    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$key}\r\n\r\n";
  
  socket_write($user->socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));
  $user->handshake=true;
  console($upgrade);
  console("Done handshaking...");
  return true;
}
```

I used phpwebsocket source code, both for the **client** (http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/+phpwebsocket/client.html) and the **server** (http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/+phpwebsocket/server.php).

At this point, I tested the application. Follows the server debug:

```
Server Started : 2011-10-30 13:45:41
Master socket  : Resource id #4
Listening on   : localhost port 12345

Resource id #5 CONNECTED!

Requesting handshake...
GET /phpwebsocket/server.php HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:12345
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Key: +S/J2jcp/UKIS1HTW0n1/w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8


Handshaking...
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: LEULWidwXDxY02iv3O+xksrxFz4=


Done handshaking...
< ��z�}p
> ��z�}p not understood
Resource id #5 DISCONNECTED!
```

And this is the client debug:

```
WebSocket - status 0
Welcome - status 1
Sent: hello
Disconnected - status 3
```

What I did was simply connect the client and send the command 'Hello'.
As you can see, server received encoded data and not plaintext: why?

I'm looking for someone who helps me to develop html5 websocket with hybi-17.

Cyaz

PS: **this** ([Implementing handshake for hybi-17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908306/implementing-handshake-for-hybi-17)) topic and **this one** ([Decoding network chars (HTML5 Websocket)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912772/decoding-network-chars-html5-websocket)) might help.

PPS: I tested on **Chromium 15**.0.874.106~r107270-0ubuntu0.11.04.1

Comment: You need to decode the messages you obtain; hybi includes a relatively complex framing mechanism (compared to the hixie draft). You can't "just" read the incoming bytes. I posted some decoding algorithm previously at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040078/how-to-deconstruct-data-frames-in-websockets-hybi-08/7045885#7045885.

Comment: Thank you pimvdb! I did it! Now you can view the solution at the top of the original topic ;) Cyaz

Comment: Sorry pimvdb but I have some problem with the payload length. Well, I always got '0' when I try to get the length with $msg[1] & 127 (or 0x7F). In my particular case, the buffer isn't an array but a string: so the code would be substr($msg, 1, 1) & 127. It doesn't work anyway. Why? Why I can't get the payload length following your istruction? Any ideas?

Comment: I've almost no knowledge of PHP, but if you're using a string of characters, then the underlying character codes represent the values. You of course cannot do `character & 127`; it only works with numbers. You'd better build an array where each element corresponds with the character code in the string.

Comment: Like: http://codepad.org/EiubBUSl.

Comment: Great and thanks a lot pimvdb! Now, the length is got by 'ord (buffer[1]) & 127' and it works fine :D

Comment: You guys should use $buffer{1}. This is how you correctly reference a single character within a string, even if it will let you use the [] syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode solution (thanks to @pimvdb):

```
$len = $masks = $data = $decoded = null;

$len = ord ($buffer[1]) & 127;

if ($len === 126) {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 4, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 8);
}
else if ($len === 127) {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 10, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 14);
}
else {
  $masks = substr ($buffer, 2, 4);
  $data = substr ($buffer, 6);
}

for ($index = 0; $index < strlen ($data); $index++) {
  $decoded .= $data[$index] ^ $masks[$index % 4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This encode function is great except that chrome 19 doesn't like the data being masked. I get this error after sending the first message to server:
"A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client."

I couldn't figure out how to not mask the data being sent to the server until I found a github example that works and has a flag you can set to not mask the data frames.
https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket

I had found this updated version of the phpwebsocket code:
http://www.wilky.it/phpwebsocket-new-version/
One thing you need to fix in this to make it work is replace this line at line 234:
preg_match ("#Sec-WebSocket-Origin: (.*?)\r\n#", $buffer, $match) && $origin = $match[1];
with
preg_match ("#Origin: (.*?)\r\n#", $buffer, $match) && $origin = $match[1];

Then to fix the error in chrome: "A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client." do the following:
I fixed the replaced the encode function with the one in the connection.php file in lemmingzshadow's github and it started working. The function is called: hybi10Encode in the \server\lib\WebSocket\connection.php file.
change this parameter in the function encode: $masked = true to $masked = false
So we have 2 versions that work now in chrome and firefox 12!